# Pink Panther's background song

Tags: the-pink-panther

Some chapters of pink panthers cartoon have a background  music with a kind of extended version of the classic pink panthers theme (minute 1:00 in the attached video), I would like to know if this song have a name and if exists in spotify or youtube as a complete song.

Comment: This is what I found on Spotify: https://open.spotify.com/track/1QPRmX2e3EZWskuOe5QqxM

Comment: you can listen to the theme and other music from the Pink Panther on Youtube.

Answer (score 3):

The theme music of the Pink Panther was written by Henry Mancini for the Pink Panther films and is orchestral (like the Star Wars themes). It is not a song.